# Ubuntu 16.04 public wifi connection failure "The request is invalid due to malformed syntax or invalid data."

Tags: authentication, wifi, 400, bad-request

I use Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop and I can't connect public library's free wifi. First, It shows this error when I try to open **HTTP** pages:

[Open me in new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8700.png)

When I try to open **https** pages, it says "This site can’t be reached" (ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR). Then I tried to connect to my mobile phone. It showed authentication page and successfully connected.
I tried to google this issue and all of them showed how to resolve it from admin's perspective, not a word about what user can do. Then I asked help from library's network admin. Unfortunately, He can't help either. Any solution will be strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the library's network server for wifi access requires a CA Certificate to validate authentication with the RADIUS server.
Recommend you:

1. apply any available security updates to your Ubuntu installation, to make sure you've installed the latest patches for the openSSL vulnerabilities identified at the beginning of the year (refer to https://threatpost.com/latest-ubuntu-update-includes-openssl-fixes/123513/).
2. Check to make sure your ubuntu network settings are using auto proxy and not a manually configured one.
3. install the generic security certificates and follow steps similar to those outlines for Ubuntu users trying to connect to the University of Michigan's wifi network (which has a similar setup):  http://documentation.its.umich.edu/content/wifi-manually-configuring-your-ubuntu-linux-device-mwireless